# Docker registry: Limit access by account to subset of images

Tags: docker, registry

Maybe a simple-to-answer Question: How can I set up a private docker reposiory and limit the Access to only a subset of the Images there that one can pull ? E.g. I have Image1 and Image2 pushed, but want to allow one Image2 being pullable by account USER1 ?

Comment: May there is already a Concept of user Groups, etc for this ?

Answer (score 2):

This tends to get into the commercial offerings of docker (DTR). The spec itself for the registry includes all of the capabilities for auth, and you can configure a simple htpasswd based login on the standalone registry. However for the next step up, you get into a token server which docker doesn't have an open source implementation of themselves. You could work around this limitation by deploying multiple registry servers, each with a different set of users in a htpasswd file.

There are various third party implementations of the docker registry that may include these features. In the open source space, there's a project called [cesanta/docker_auth](https://github.com/cesanta/docker_auth) that works with docker's stand alone registry and does exactly what you're looking for. The next step up is the [harbor](https://goharbor.io) project that should be all most organizations need from a registry, but may be more complicated and have more overhead for a small project.